# ASP.NET (C#) event to happen before printing

Tags: c#, printing

I have a web form in ASP.Net with C# code behind. It's a simple thing, and I'm pretty new so I'm kind of stuck.

In the source code of the web form I have a button called "print" that looks like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPrint" runat="server" onclientclick="window.print();" Text="Print" />
```

No problem. In the code behind I have this:

```
 protected void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get current Date/Time
    string dateTime = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + ", at " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();

    //set it to labelDate
    lblDate.Text = "Requested on " + dateTime; 

}
```

So the problem is that when I hit the print button, the form prints before the code executes and stamps the label (lblDate.Text).

Soooo... my noob question is how to get that date/time stamp to process before the form prints?

Thanks for your advice.

Mark

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Mark, and I'm glad your first experience was so successful! I'd like to ask you to comment instead of answering when you want to thank someone, though; this isn't a traditional forum like you may be used to. Since as an unregistered user you can't delete your answer here, I've done it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
protected void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //get current Date/Time
    string dateTime = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString() + ", at " + DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();

    //set it to labelDate
    lblDate.Text = "Requested on " + dateTime; 

 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "key", "window.print();", true);

}
```

Comment: The only problem with this is your doing a full server post back to accomplish something plain old javascript can handle just fine. If that isnt a problem this solution would work fine.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I completely spaced on the javascript side of things there. =) In the end, just adding the quick line did the trick. This is on our intranet site and we're a small company so no worries. I'm a noob so that why I do so much server side stuff.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

My first instinct would be to ditch the server side event, and populate the time stamp with javascript before the print call.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling a windows.print(), call a function that adds the Requested datetime.
That will do the work.